# Retornar JSON com ASP.NET/C#

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, json

Tenho o seguintes códigos

Default.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* Relógio */
        function startTime() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetNetworkTime',
                data: "{}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (dados) {
                    var m;
                    var s;
                    if (dados.minuto < 10) {
                        m = "0" + dados.minuto;
                    } else {
                        m = dados.minuto;
                    }
                    if (dados.segundo < 10) {
                        s = "0" + dados.segundo;
                    } else {
                        s = dados.segundo;
                    }
                    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = dados.hora + ":" + m + ":" + s;
                }
            });
            t = setTimeout('startTime()', 500);
        };
    </script>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System.Web.Services;

namespace LPGPontoKH
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetNetworkTime()
        {
            DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;

            var resultado = new
            {
                hora = datetime.Hour,
                minuto = datetime.Minute,
                segundo = datetime.Second
            };
            //O JavaScriptSerializer vai fazer o web service retornar JSON
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            return js.Serialize(resultado);
        }

    }
}
```

Minha função javascript startTime é executada, porém o método GetNetworkTime não é chamado. Alguém sabe o que ta faltando?

Erro de log Gerado.

> {"Message":"Falha ao
>   autenticar.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException‌​"}

Comment: Acho que você está misturando MVC com Web Forms. Não sei se essa forma vai funcionar.

Comment: Sei muito pouco de Web Forms @CiganoMorrisonMendez Pesquisei e vi que assim que fazia, mas não sei. Preciso fazer pra Web Forms mesmo nesse caso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer essa chamada ajax funcionar na sua aplicação WebForms, você vai precisar alterar a configuração de rota.

No arquivo "~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs", altere de:

`settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;`

Para:

`settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;`

Depois de fazer essa alteração e rodar a aplicação novamente, você verá que o WebMethod GetNetworkTime() será executado no code behind da página.